# Independent with as statement postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

How can I reference different tables the are created with `WITH ... AS` statements?

This is my code

```sql
WITH TABLE1 AS
(
    SELECT code 
    FROM Product 
    WHERE pname <> "cucumber"
),
TABLE2 AS
(
    SELECT bid, rdate, rtime, code 
    FROM Purchase
    WHERE code IN TABLE1
),
TABLE3 AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS AMOUNT, bid, rdate, rtime 
    FROM TABLE2
    NATURAL JOIN Receipt
    WHERE total > 50
    GROUP BY bid, rdate, rtime;
),
TABLE4 AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE3
    WHERE AMOUNT = ALL(SELECT MIN(AMOUNT)
                       FROM TABLE3)
)
SELECT * 
FROM Receipt 
WHERE bid, rdate, rtime  = ALL(SELECT bid, rdate, rtime 
                               FROM TABLE4);
```

The tables are

- Product (code (Product code), pname, descr, utype, uprice, manu, sid (SUPPLIER ID))
- Receipt ((PK)(bid, rdate, rtime), ptype, total)
- Purchase ((PK)(bid, rdate, rtime, code) , units)

and the question is "find the Receipt with the least amount of suppliers, where the total is more than 50, and in which no cucumbers have been bought.
(I provide this information in order to prevent asking about a X Y problem)

As you can see, I am trying to build it so that each new table created relies on the prevision one. But when I do it like that, I get an error that I can not reference the prevision tables (probably as it is count as the same query)

Trying semicolon between statements did not work either.

Comment: `with` does not "create" any tables. `with x as (...) select * from x` is exactly the same as `select * from (...) as x` - you can't reference any of the aliases outside of the CTE, if that it was you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Receipt 
WHERE bid, rdate, rtime  = ALL (SELECT bid, rdate, rtime 
                                FROM TABLE4);
```

is the problem. It has nothing to do with your CTEs.

If you want to compare multiple columns you have to enclose them in parentheses on the left side:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Receipt 
WHERE (bid, rdate, rtime) = ALL(SELECT bid, rdate, rtime 
                                FROM TABLE4);
```

---

Additionally: `"cucumber"` references a *column* named `cucumber`. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL:

```
pname <> 'cucumber'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, don't repeat `with`.  Second, refer to them as you would any table or view:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
      SELECT code
      FROM Product
      WHERE pname <> 'cucumber'
     ),
     cte2 AS (
      SELECT bid, rdate, rtime, code
      FROM Purchase
      WHERE code IN (SELECT cte1.code FROM cte1)
     ),
     . . .
```

Other notes:

- Use single quotes for strings.  Although some databases support double quotes, just use the SQL standard.
- Qualify column references, particularly when you have more than one table reference.
- I changed the names of the CTEs from "table" to "CTE".  I think "table" is misleading.

Comment: when I try to do it this way, I get error such as: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TABLE1"
LINE 14: WHERE code IN TABLE1
                       ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "TABLE1"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 160. Thats exactly my problem

Comment: @avivgood2 . . . I don't know what line 14 is in our code.  Based on your sample, it is the `WHERE` in the second CTE and the above code would not have this error.  Follow the template.